# Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wifi, hotspot

Using the Connectivity Manager Class we can get access to either wifi or Internet Network:

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

// ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
  // ...
}
```

where `0` and `1` respectively refers to mobile and wifi connection

If my Android device is connected to both, can we switch between any of the networks or can we disable any of the networks? Like using a function:

```
connec.getNetworkInfo(0).setState(NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution  for mobile data disable option ?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I know of enabling or disabling wifi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

where status may be `true` or `false` as per requirement.

**Edit:**

You also need the following permissions in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Also at manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />`

Comment: Does this differ from wifiManager.reconnect()? What about wifiManager.reassociate()? Also in the approach above if you wanted to reset the WiFi could you call wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false) and wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true) back to back? Or would you have to disable it first, then wait for some signal (broadcast receiver etc.) before enabling it again?

Comment: If you want demo tutorial fot then its here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/turn-wifi-on-off-programatically-android_98

Comment: `“<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />”` is also needed.

Comment: Is it possible to control WiFi in M device from Application?

Comment: [Deprecated in API level 29](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)). See [BigSt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289575/9157799).

Answer (score 32):

**To Enable WiFi:**

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

**To Disable WiFi:**

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

**Note:
To access with WiFi state, we have to add following permissions inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS 
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

Comment: only CHANGE_WIFI_STATE is necessary, at least in Android 4.2

Comment: UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS is only for system apps

Comment: From Android Q , you can not be directly on/off the wifi

Answer (score 12):

A complete solution:

```
try {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "\"SSIDName\"";
    wc.preSharedKey  = "\"password\"";
    wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED; 

    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers
        .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers
        .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

    boolean b=wifi.isWifiEnabled();
    if (b) {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(context, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(context, "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Reference: http://amitkumar-android.blogspot.com/p/installation-steps.html

Comment: The call to set the wifi manager with the wifi configuration is missing: wifi.addNetwork(wc);

Comment: Why would you hard-code your SSID and password?  Not a good idea.

Comment: @lifeson106 I think it's only for the purpose of demonstration.

Answer (score 11):

In **Android Q (Android 10)** you can't enable/disable wifi programmatically anymore. Use **Settings Panel** to toggle wifi connectivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    // can also use `Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI` to enable/disable only WiFi
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
} else {
    // use previous solution, add appropriate permissions to AndroidManifest file (see answers above)
    (this.context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager)?.apply { isWifiEnabled = true /*or false*/ }
}
```

Comment: [Settings.Panel official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel)

Comment: Found this helpfull

Answer (score 4):

To enable disable Wifi use the `WifiManager` class to get system(android device) services for Wifi :

```
WifiManager wifi =(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Now the object `wifi` of the `WifiManager` class is used to get the wifi status:

```
if(wifi.isWifiEnabled())
    //Perform Operation
else
    //Other Operation
```

And most importantly do not forget to give the following permission in your Android Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

To get detailed info and full sample code  of the project for enable/disable Wifi on android visit [my website link](http://jannatyahan.com/android-applications-development-tutorial-to-enabledisable-wifi-in-android-apps/).

Answer (score 3):

This method is deprecated now from now starting with Android Q.

Try This will really help.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {// if build version is less than Q try the old traditional method
                    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                        btnOnOff.setText("Wifi ONN");
                    } else {
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                        btnOnOff.setText("Wifi OFF");
                    }
                } else {// if it is Android Q and above go for the newer way    NOTE: You can also use this code for less than android Q also
                    Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI);
                    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 1);
                }
```

Comment: Worth pointing to new/preferred method with example?

Answer (score 1):

add this permission in your manifest and than use the above code to change WiFi state:

```
 <!--permission ge enable and disable WIFI in android-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not access the context object directly.
My solution is as following:

```
Context appContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
var wifiManager = (WifiManager)appContext.GetSystemService(WifiService);
wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(state);
```

Also I had to change some writings eg. WIFI_SERVICE vs. WifiService.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to enable/disable wifi *on pre Android 10* devices using the following code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = 
(WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);

But **note** that it is not possible to do this anymore on Android 10 and probably going ahead as well.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141011684

Answer (score 1):

Android 10 (Q) onwards wifi can not be enabled/disabled you need to open the setting intent,

```
// for android Q and above
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Intent panelIntent = new 
Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY);
            startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0);
        } else {
            // for previous android version
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
```

In manifest,

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
```