# Android app crash when first network is switched off and then switched on

Tags: android, connectivity

I am using the following function to check network connectivity but application crashes when wifi status is swapped

```
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connec.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the error you get?

Comment: Post the stack trace. It seems reasonable to me that NetworkInfo would throw an exception (that you aren't catching) if you weren't connected to a network.

Comment: Does your app crash if the WiFi status is changed while your app is in the middle of performing a network operation?  Or does it crash if the WiFi status is changed and you *then* run your app?

Comment: sadly it never comes in debug mode

Comment: first after loosing connectivity , back button is pressed to reach the "page in which crash occurs".. then an alert is shown(There is no network connectivity and i press OK)..then i switch on the wifi... then there is a refresh button in which using the above fn .. connectivity is checked.. then after a blank screen app crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it took some time to shift between networks...

So Now if we disable the wifi it automatically get connected to mobile network after few seconds.. and if we enable the wifi then it get connected to wifi network again...

The thread in your application is checking the connectivity before that shift...

check the conversation here

[Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programatically-andriod)

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a NullPointerException?

I use the following method:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch(NullPointerException n) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException comes under unchecked Exception category. It should never be checked. NullPointerException indicates a bug that a programmer forgot to bind the object to its reference. and program should terminate if it comes.