# How to use connect to a wireless access point using android?

Tags: android, linux

I would like to develop a simple Android application that asks the password and ESSID and then do the wi-fi login.

Is it possible with an activity application?

Thank you!

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d8c1ffe68445f76/ab675ca5cb7595e2?q=Change+APN+settings+programmatically&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Asking for ESSID to login to WiFi sounds pretty lame to be honest. :) In case you are looking to programatically enable/disable WiFi [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically).