# what are possible arguments could be passed to getNetworkInfo()

Tags: android, network-programming, android-wifi

I have checked the suggested question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically), but when I checked the documentation regarding the method `getNetworkInfo()`[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(int)), there was no documentation regarding the possible integer values this method could handle. For an example, if I passed `0` to the `getNetworkInfo()` this means I am checking he mobile network, and if it is `1`, I am checking the status of the `WiFi`.

Is there any other possible values? Why they are not in the documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

```
public static final int TYPE_NONE        = -1;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE      = 0;

public static final int TYPE_WIFI        = 1;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_MMS  = 2;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL = 3;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_DUN  = 4;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI = 5;

public static final int TYPE_WIMAX       = 6;

public static final int TYPE_BLUETOOTH   = 7;

public static final int TYPE_DUMMY       = 8;

public static final int TYPE_ETHERNET    = 9;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_FOTA = 10;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_IMS  = 11;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_CBS  = 12;

public static final int TYPE_WIFI_P2P    = 13;

public static final int TYPE_MOBILE_IA = 14;
```

Comment: oh thank you, i have checked the link but i did not find the numbers (-1 to 14) assigned to each type? where di you get them

Comment: hi, i marked your answer as a correct answer because I have checeked it, but till now i did not find that list o integer values passed to the method. kindly woud you please give me the exact lin where i can find thoses integers?

Comment: `sdk\sources\android-21\android\net\ConnectivityManager.java` or http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#ConnectivityManager