# Turn On/Off WiFi Hotspot Programmatically on Android Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: android, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, hotspot

I have come across this thread ([Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)) which is very similar to what I wanted to ask. I have tried the solution provided by an answer posted by Ashish Sahu (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1780737/ashish-sahu) which seems to work perfectly on other Android versions aside from Marshmallow (6.0).

Is there anyway to toggle and setup a WiFi Hotspot on Android Marshmallow? I tried using mHotspot (http://www.mhotspot.com/) which can do the job on Android Marshmallow but I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I manage to fix it by using the code provided my Ashish Sahu in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically. And fix my targetSdkVersion to be lower than 23 in build.gradle.
The code provided by Lex Hobbit in the answer also works too but the code provided by Ashish Sahu, as mention before, looks cleaner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer for this question is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class WifiAPController extends Activity {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public String password;
    public String APname;

    private static int g;
    private static int h;
    private static int i;
    private static int j;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private String logTAG;
    private int wifiState;
    private boolean o;

    class wifiControllerTask extends AsyncTask {
        WifiAPController wifiAPControllerClass;
        boolean a;
        boolean b;
        Context mContext;

        public wifiControllerTask(WifiAPController wifiAPController, boolean arg3, boolean arg4, Context context) {
            this.wifiAPControllerClass = wifiAPController;
            this.a = arg3;
            this.b = arg4;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        protected Void a(Void[] arg3) {
            try {
                WifiAPController.wifiToggle(this.wifiAPControllerClass, this.a);
            } catch (Exception v0) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void a() {
            int sdkCurrentVersion = 21;
            try {
                if (this.a) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < sdkCurrentVersion) {
                        return;
                    }

                    this.wifiAPControllerClass.wifiToggle(this.mContext);
                    return;
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < sdkCurrentVersion) {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception v0) {
                Log.e("noti error", v0.getMessage());
            }
        }

        protected void a(Void arg2) {
            super.onPostExecute(arg2);
            try {
                this.a();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException v0) {
                try {
                    this.a();
                } catch (Exception v0_1) {
                }
            }

            if (this.b) {
                this.wifiAPControllerClass.finish();
            }
        }

        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] arg2) {
            return this.a(((Void[]) arg2));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object arg1) {
            this.a(((Void) arg1));
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }


    static {
        WifiAPController.g = 0;
        WifiAPController.h = 0;
        WifiAPController.i = 1;
        WifiAPController.j = 4;
    }

    public WifiAPController() {
        super();
        this.a = 2;
        this.b = 3;
        this.logTAG = "WifiAP";
        this.wifiState = -1;
        this.o = false;
    }

    static int wifiToggle(WifiAPController wifiAPController, boolean wifiToggleFlag) {
        return wifiAPController.wifiToggle(wifiToggleFlag);
    }

    private void initWifiAPConfig(WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration){
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "SomeName";
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "SomeKey1";
        wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    }

    private int wifiToggle(boolean wifiToggleFlag) {
        int wifiState;
        String stateString;
        StringBuilder message;
        long sleepTimeout = 500;
        int maxAttemptCount = 10;
        int errorState = -1;
        Log.d(this.logTAG, "*** setWifiApEnabled CALLED **** " + wifiToggleFlag);
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        initWifiAPConfig(wifiConfiguration);
        if ((wifiToggleFlag) && this.wifiState == errorState) {
            this.wifiState = this.wifiManager.getWifiState();
        }

        if (!(!wifiToggleFlag || this.wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() == null)) {
            Log.d(this.logTAG, "disable wifi: calling");
            this.wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            int attemptCount = maxAttemptCount;
            while (attemptCount > 0) {
                if (this.wifiManager.getWifiState() == 1) {
                    break;
                }

                Log.d(this.logTAG, "disable wifi: waiting, pass: " + (10 - attemptCount));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeout);
                    --attemptCount;
                } catch (Exception v4_1) {
                }
            }

            Log.d(this.logTAG, "disable wifi: done, pass: " + (10 - attemptCount));
        }

        try {
            message = new StringBuilder();
            stateString = wifiToggleFlag ? "enabling" : "disabling";
            Log.d(this.logTAG, message.append(stateString).append(" wifi ap: calling").toString());
            Log.d(this.logTAG, this.APname);
            Log.d(this.logTAG, this.password);
            Log.d(this.logTAG, "" + this.wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class).invoke(this.wifiManager, wifiConfiguration, true).toString());
            int res = this.wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
            Log.d(this.logTAG, "" + res);
            wifiState = (int) this.wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState").invoke(this.wifiManager);
            Log.d(this.logTAG, "" + wifiState);
        } catch (Exception v0_1) {
            Log.e("wifi", v0_1.getMessage());
            wifiState = errorState;
        }

        while (maxAttemptCount > 0) {
            if (this.wifiToggle() != WifiAPController.h && this.wifiToggle() != this.b && this.wifiToggle() != WifiAPController.j) {
                break;
            }
            message = new StringBuilder();
            stateString = wifiToggleFlag ? "enabling" : "disabling";
            Log.d(this.logTAG, message.append(stateString).append(" wifi ap: waiting, pass: ").append(10 - maxAttemptCount).toString());
            sleepTimeout = 500;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTimeout);
                --maxAttemptCount;
            } catch (Exception v0_1) {
            }
        }
        message = new StringBuilder();
        stateString = wifiToggleFlag ? "enabling" : "disabling";
        Log.d(this.logTAG, message.append(stateString).append(" wifi ap: done, pass: ").append(10 - maxAttemptCount).toString());

        if (!wifiToggleFlag) {
            if ((this.wifiState >= WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING && this.wifiState <= WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN) || (this.o)) {
                Log.d(this.logTAG, "enable wifi: calling");
                this.wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }

            this.wifiState = errorState;
            return wifiState;
        }
        return wifiState;
    }

    public int wifiToggle() {
        int result;
        int v4 = 10;
        try {
            result = (int) this.wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState").invoke(this.wifiManager);
        } catch (Exception v0) {
            result = -1;
        }

        if (result >= v4) {
            WifiAPController.g = v4;
        }

        WifiAPController.h = WifiAPController.g;
        WifiAPController.i = WifiAPController.g + 1;
        this.a = WifiAPController.g + 2;
        this.b = WifiAPController.g + 3;
        WifiAPController.j = WifiAPController.g + 4;
        return result;
    }

    public void wifiToggle(Context context) {
        Intent v0 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void wifiToggle(String apname, String pass, WifiManager wifiManager, Context context) {
        boolean v2 = true;
        if (this.wifiManager == null) {
            this.wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        }

        this.APname = apname;
        this.password = pass;
        int v0 = this.wifiToggle() == this.b || this.wifiToggle() == this.a ? 1 : 0;
        if (v0 != 0) {
            v2 = false;
        }

        new wifiControllerTask(this, v2, false, context).execute(new Void[0]);
    }
}
```

Also, in main Activity you should call like this:

```
    WifiAPController wifiAPController  = new WifiAPController();
    wifiAPController.wifiToggle("mHotspot", "12345678", wifiManager, context);
```

Don't forget about permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I tested this on Nexus 6 with Marshmallow(6.0)

Comment: I'm sorry I took too long to reply... I try to use your code but I'm a beginner and couldn't fulfill the requirement for the arguments in  wifiAPController.wifiToggle... Could you help with the wifiManager and context? Your help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: This method does not work. I tested on my S6 running Android 6.0.1. The old method, simply using reflection, would cause a crash due to WRITE_SETTINGS not being granted. I don't think this is possible via 3rd party apps anymore.

Comment: anybody verify that? I do the reflection thing, and it worked find until android 6.0.1 on my s6 just like you. Hoping upon hope they didn't break that permanently.

Comment: Folks, use [this note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically) as wrote @user2826067. This one more cleaner and works on 6.0-7.1 Android.