# Can't turn-on WiFi by a class object

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-wifi, wifimanager

I know that I can turn-On WiFi in the OnCreate() by a WifiManager object. But my project demands an Object-Oriented Approach rather than simply using a WiFi functionality. So i made a class:

```
public class WiFiSenderBase extends Activity implements Sender
{  
    public static WifiManager wifi;

    WiFiSenderBase()
    {
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean TurnOn()
    {
        if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

now in the MainActivity class and onCreate() :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ToggleButton t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1_ref);
        final WiFiSenderBase wifi = new WiFiSenderBase();
        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    wifi.TurnOn();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

now, the problem is that the app crashes on onCreate() itself and makes a toast

**Unfortunately, App has stopped**

I think that there is a problem in instantiation of WiFiSenderBase class in the MainActivity, as WiFiSenderBase also extends Activity class, but If I do not extend Activity in WiFiSenderBase then I do not get to use the ***getSystemService()***. Any help will be appreciable.

p.s. using eclipse mars, and all the necessary imports have been made

Comment: Are you sure that you have the `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission set? I'm sure that `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` is also required.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Yes, I did that.

Comment: I'm not sure if these are required or not as well. I've never used them myself. `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`

Comment: @RayfenWindspear They are required, but why can't i use a public class's  method to turn on WiFi?

Comment: Perhaps see this question. In the answer comments, there is also a tutorial with source. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: No sir, they also create wifimanager objects in MainActivity only, still that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I turn-On WiFi in the OnCreate() by a WifiManager object. And pass it to the constructor of WiFiSenderBase.:

```
public class WiFiSenderBase implements Sender
{  
    public static WifiManager wifi;

    WiFiSenderBase(WifiManager man)
    {
        wifi = man;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean TurnOn()
    {
        if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

now in the MainActivity class and onCreate() :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public WifiManager wifiman;
    ToggleButton t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wifiman = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final WiFiSenderBase wifi = new WiFiSenderBase(wifiman);
        t = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1_ref);
        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    wifi.TurnOn();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

now, the problem is solved.

p.s. using eclipse mars, and all the necessary imports have been made