# How to automatically send a push notification if wifi goes off?

Tags: android, notifications, wifi

I found [someone who](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-create-android-notifications-707254/) asked about enable/disable internet connection and [someone else who](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically) teaches how to build a notification.
So i mixed them up and did this:

```
 public void sendNotification() {

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
    } else {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle("TURN ON WIFI!!")
                        .setContentText("You should turn it back on!");


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

}
```

But it isn't working =(

Comment: I never did it, but i know that when the wifi goes off a broadcast is send, you need to receive that broadcast then send the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a broadcast receiver which listens to SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION.
Look it up here it has already been achieved.

[How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android/5890553#5890553)