# How to Block WIFI and GPS on Click? means user will not have any authorization to change the status of them

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-gps

I have Two buttons to disable WIFI and GPS functionality. On Clicking on button user will not allowed to change the state of gps or wifi. it has to completely block the wifi and gps. Any one having solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically

Comment: You can't tweak System settings. It's not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)

Comment: then how App locker are able to block wifi? @RahulChandrabhan

Comment: @SubinBabu no it is not. that question is about enable or disable wifi. here question is to block wifi facility to user.

Comment: Sorry to say, Reaccept a new answer that is answered after my answer after a long time. This is a pure violation of StackOverflow policies to get a reputation. Also, the answer is exactly the same answer as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

also, add permission. You can find the details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931094/6299045)

Comment: Sorry to say. this is not requirement. i want to completely block wifi. if i will use that code. if i will click on wifi it will get on.

Comment: You can disable WiFi again, if the user enables it.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the following permissions in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

---

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

Comment: Sorry to say. this is not requirement. i want to completely block wifi. if i will use that code. if i will click on wifi it will get on.

Comment: You have to set status to True or false

Comment: after that what if user will click wifi  button ??

Comment: you have to handle that kind of scenario

Comment: i have created a Broadcast Receiver to handle that. when someone is clicking to disable wifi i am calling that receiver. and enabling it. but while making it enable the receiver catch that event and going to a continuous loop.

Answer (score 0):

to Block wifi Completely we need a Broadcast receiver who will detect the event for wifi status change. And if the status is on we need to make it off.. by this i resoled it issue.