# Android: Switch between WiFi and Mobile Data manually, without rooting

Tags: android

I'm making an application should have the option to choose Mobile Data or Wifi to access the internet without rooting the device. How to do it?

Comment: Well, this is too broad to be answered.

Comment: For wifi, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically) and for data connection see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)