# Enable Disable WiFi on Android 29

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-wifi, wifimanager

```
public boolean WifiManager.setWifiEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. Starting with
>   Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable
>   Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and
>   will have no effect. If apps are targeting an older SDK (
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

How can we disable WiFi on Android 29?

Comment: this is the intended behavior and will not be fixed, this sucks, android 10 sucks overall. Scoped storage being the most annoying
https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/03/29/death-external-storage-where-google.html

Answer (score 4):

In **Android Q (Android 10, API level 29)** you can't enable/disable wifi programmatically anymore. Use **Settings Panel** to toggle wifi connectivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
} else {
    // add appropriate permissions to AndroidManifest file (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically/61289575)
    (this.context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager)?.apply { isWifiEnabled = true /*or false*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a much simpler way of detecting the operating system version:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
else
{
   Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI);
   startActivityForResult(panelIntent,1);
}
```

Basically, if the OS version is less than Android Q, use the WifiManager class object to enable/disable the use of Wi-Fi; otherwise, use implicit Intents to disable Wi-Fi.

Comment: If targetSdkVersion < 29, wifiManager.setWifiEnabled works as intended on ALL android version, including newer ones. If targetSdkVersion >= 29, wifiManager.setWifiEnabled fails and returns false for ALL android version, including older ones. So what's the point of this if-else logic?

Answer (score 3):

solved!

```
private void setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "svc wifi", enabled ?
                "enable" :
                "disable" });
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

happily works on api 29

obviously, this requires root

does NOT require android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: Another variant to this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262649/2677764.

Answer (score 1):

Android Q has restricted this and developers can't disable wifi programmatically. your app will continue to work and can disable wifi if your targetSdkVersion <= 28

Answer (score 0):

Toggling WiFi will not be allowed by apps starting from Android Q according to Google.

Here's the issue on their issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554616