# How to access default implementation in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android development.
How could I able to invoke the Android default function from my own App?

The feature I would like to get is the "Cast" or "Wi-Fi" icon.
Instead of scroll through the menu, I would like to access it with its own App button.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930990/android-how-to-enable-disable-wifi-or-internet-connection-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```